# How to show a vertical scrollbar in html select when number of elements exceeds a specific count?

Tags: select, scrollbar

I've encountered a problem. We know that the select will show a vertical scrollbar when number of elements exceeds 20 in chrome(30 in firefox). Can we find a way to show a vertical scrollbar  when the number of elements exceeds a specific count. Below is an example:

[image: An example]

Thanks for any advices.

Answer (score -1):

Use size in your vertical scrollbar to change the default value

Comment: Thanks! I am a little confused. Can you give me more details? Do you mean the size attribute in select? I tried this, but in this way the elements will always show. What I want is to show the elements and scrollbar when the drop down button is clicked.

Answer (score -2):

Set the "`size`" attribute of your list to the specific count value.
example:

```
 <select size="yourSpecificValue">
 </select>
```

if the items in the list exceeds this value the scrollbar will be automatically added.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've tried this method, but in this way the elements and scrollbar (if existed) will always show. What I want is to show the elements and scrollbar when the drop down button is clicked. Any more advices?

Comment: for that you have to remove the "size" attribute from the <select> tag. then if it is clicked, the elements will show up.

Comment: That is the fact. Maybe I did not express my question clearly. Can we figure out a way to keep the drop down button work and show a vertical scrollbar when the number of elements exceeds a specific count after it clicked?